# Double underlined text for android

Tags: react-native

I found that to have double underline in text we have `textDecorationStyle enum('solid', 'double', 'dotted', 'dashed')` - available for **iOS** but, I didn't find anything similar for **android** in `react-native`.

Does anyone know how can we do this?